# Help! My wallpaper is broken after installing Pantheon Shell?

Tags: desktop-background, pantheon

Earlier today, I installed Pantheon Shell, and got an unpleasant surprise.  My wallpaper doesn't work!  It doesn't work in either Pantheon, GNOME 3 Fallback, and Unity 2D.  Instead, the background is gray, and I can't get rid of it.  What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

A possible fix is:

1. Install dconf-tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Open `dconf-editor`
3. Navigate to: desktop -> wallpaper -> picture path.
4. Type/paste the path to your wallpaper and press enter.

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Since I am new to Ubuntu, I have no idea how the dconf editor works (which I downloaded) and what a wallpaper path is.  Please try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: if you drag a file into a terminal window it will tell you the path to the file inside two **'**

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, but inside "Desktop", "Wallpaper" does not exist.  I suppose in needs to be reinstalled somehow.

Comment: The pantheon-wallpaper app is probably running in Gnome3-Fallback and Unity2D. If so: type killall pantheon-wallpaper in a terminal. this does not work in Pantheon itself...

Comment: @Jonathan: Here is my response once I did that - "pantheon-wallpaper: no process found"

Comment: Should I uninstall Pantheon?  None of the above work.  Or should I somehow find a way to install it?

Comment: A last thing you could try is: install gnome tweak tool and look at the "have file manager handle the desktop" (desktop category) switch. and set it to on if it's off.

Comment: IT'S BACK!!! THE WALLPAPER IS BACK!!!  Sorry if I was overreacting.  Case closed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. I uninstalled all pantheon apps and the problem persisted, then I disabled and re-enabled draw-background in org/gnome/desktop/background with dconf-editor and voila, my wallpaper showed up. Hope this helps!